# MSSQL WHERE YEAR clause returning all dates instead of date specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause

Junior here with no one to help me but the void of the internet and my googling skills are mediocre at best.

The following syntax returns the information I need however, it's giving me ALL dates in the table and ignoring the WHERE clause. There are 3 tables I'm trying to Join: 'ProductHistory' is the main one, with one column needed from 'Product' and a date field from the third table 'MainJobDetails'.

```
SELECT [ProductHistory].[Type]
    ,[ProductHistory].[Ref]
    ,[ProductHistory].[JobNo]
    ,[ProductHistory].[Quantity]
    ,[ProductHistory].[PurchasePrice]
    ,[ProductHistory].[UnitPrice]
    ,[ProductHistory].[UnitDesc]
    ,[ProductHistory].[ProductID]
    ,[ProductHistory].[Location]
    ,[ProductHistory].[UserID]
    ,[Product].[Description]
    ,[Product].[StkRef1]
    ,[MainJobDetails].[DespatchDate]
FROM [ProductHistory]
JOIN [Product] ON [ProductHistory].[ProductID] = [Product].[ID]
JOIN [MainJobDetails] ON [ProductHistory].[JobNo] = [MainJobDetails].[JobNo]
WHERE YEAR([MainJobDetails].[DespatchDate]) = 2020
AND MONTH([MainJobDetails].[DespatchDate]) = 11
AND [ProductHistory].[Type] = 5
OR [ProductHistory].[Type] = 6
ORDER BY [MainJobDetails].[DespatchDate] DESC
```

I've tried changing the WHERE clause to:

```
WHERE [MainJobDetails].[DespatchDate] BETWEEN '2020/10/31' AND '2020/11/30'
```

But it made no difference.

This is another similar query I've used previously and it works fine:

```
SELECT [MainJobDetails].[JobNo]
      ,[MainJobDetails].[EstimateHeaderRef]
      ,[MainJobDetails].[InvoiceCustomerName]
      ,[MainJobDetails].[JobDesc]
      ,[MainJobDetails].[DespatchDate]
      ,[FinishingInput].[Code]
      ,[FinishingInput].[Description]
      ,[FinishingInput].[Runs]
      ,[FinishingInput].[Timedb] 
  FROM [MainJobDetails]
  LEFT JOIN [FinishingInput]
  ON [MainJobDetails].[EstimateHeaderRef]=[FinishingInput].[EstimateHeaderRef]
  WHERE [MainJobDetails].[DespatchDate] BETWEEN '2020/11/01' AND '2020/12/31'
  ORDER BY [MainJobDetails].[DespatchDate] DESC
```

What am I getting wrong in the first statement?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why use `MONTH` and `YEAR`? Use proper date logic: `Yourdate >= '20200501' AND YourDate < '20200601'`. It's far better for performance as the query will then be SARGable.

Comment: When you mix `AND` and `OR` without using parentheses, you have to check the precedence rules to work out how they combine. I'd suggest you insert appropriate parentheses to make clear that the other conditions also apply when `Type` is 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `OR` condition within parentheses:

```
WHERE 
    YEAR([MainJobDetails].[DespatchDate]) = 2020
    AND MONTH([MainJobDetails].[DespatchDate]) = 11
    AND ([ProductHistory].[Type] = 5 OR [ProductHistory].[Type] = 6)
      --^-- here                                        and here --^--
```

Why you need that is because `OR` has lower priority than `AND` in logical expressions. So your original code (without the parentheses) is equivalent to:

```
WHERE 
    (
        YEAR([MainJobDetails].[DespatchDate]) = 2020
        AND MONTH([MainJobDetails].[DespatchDate]) = 11
        AND ([ProductHistory].[Type] = 5
    )
    OR [ProductHistory].[Type] = 6
```

You can see that this allows any product with Type 6, regardless of other conditions.

I would also suggest further optimizations:

- use direct filtering on the date rather than applying date functions no the stored value - this is *much* more efficient
- use `IN` instead of `OR`ed conditions

So:

```
WHERE 
        [MainJobDetails].[DespatchDate] >= '20201101'
    AND [MainJobDetails].[DespatchDate] <  '20201201'
    AND [ProductHistory].[Type] IN (5, 6)
```

Comment: Ah! of course, I didn't use >=

Comment: This worked! and the data loaded much quicker. Thank you so much. I don't know what I would do if this forum wasn't here.